# Check if a record is present in a has-many association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, rails-api

I have a rails-api application in which users can follow other users.

To check if an user already follows another user, I need to include a query in the attributes and because of that, I have always a `N+1` query problem.

Here is my code:

`Index` action in user controller:

```
def index
    @users = ::User.all.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

**The followers will always be included by a `default_scope` in the `User` model.**

index.json.jbuilder:

```
json.partial! 'attributes', collection: @users, as: :user
```

_attributes.json.jbuilder:

```
json.extract! user, :id, :firstname, :lastname, :username, :follower_count

is_follower = user.follower.find_by(id: current_user.id).present? if current_user

json.following is_follower
```

And as a result:

```
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "relationships" ON "users"."id" = "relationships"."follower_id" WHERE "relationships"."followed_id" = $1  [["followed_id", 14]]
  Rendered v1/user/users/_attributes.json.jbuilder (1.3ms)
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "relationships" ON "users"."id" = "relationships"."follower_id" WHERE "relationships"."followed_id" = $1  [["followed_id", 9]]
  Rendered v1/user/users/_attributes.json.jbuilder (1.4ms)
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "relationships" ON "users"."id" = "relationships"."follower_id" WHERE "relationships"."followed_id" = $1  [["followed_id", 13]]
```

Is there some workaround or is it somehow possible to generate a dynamic attribute in the SQL query which includes the boolean value if the user follows the other user?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought would be to eager load the followers using the `.includes` method when you get the list of users like this `@users = ::User.all.includes(:followers).paginate(page: params[:page])`. But perhaps, I'm not understanding your question correctly? Let me know if that works or if I should focus my answer on a different subject. Thanks!

EDIT: Correct answer from the comments below:

Perhaps you can try `user.followers.include?(current_user)` to make use of the pre-loaded followers association.

Comment: I have a `default scope` in my User Model which automatically includes the followers.

Comment: My mistake. I must have missed that part when I first read it. It seems like in line 2 of your `jbuilder` you are checking if the current user is included in the list of followers, but not sure what the `follower(user)` method is doing. Perhaps you can try `user.followers.include?(current_user)` to make use of the pre-loaded followers association.

Comment: Thank you very much! The ìnclude?` method solved the problem.

Comment: The `follower(user)` method was a really dangerous mistake by me. It does not load the follower which includes the `current_user`. I already fixed it and modified the question. Thanks again!